# how to convert NopCommerce project version 2.3 to 3.0?

Tags: nopcommerce

I have Currently working on NopCommerce Project which is version 2.3 but i want to Convert this project to latest version 3.0. I have already done it this project on version 2.3 . 
So how to Convert this project 3.0 Could you please help me step by step explanation i am very disappointed for it.

**Note:- Currently working on NopCommerce project version 2.3 (ASP.NET MVC4 Razor),Entity Framework 4.0 and sql server 2008**

I have following doubts:-

1. how to convert current NopCommerce project(version 2.3) to latest version(3.0).
2. NopCommerce version 3.0 supporting ASP.NET 4.5 Framework. How to convert ASP.NET4.0 to ASP.NET 4.5 this NopCommerce project

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Backup your existing database*
2. Execute upgrade.sql script over your database
3. Remove all files from the previous version except App_Data\Settings.txt and App_Data\InstalledPlugins.txt
4. Upload new site files
5. Copy back App_Data\Settings.txt and App_Data\InstalledPlugins.txt files
6. Ensure that everything is OK

*If you stored your pictures on the file system, then also backup them (\Content\Images) and copy back after upgrade

*Note:*
The updatescript can be downloaded trough the following link:

[UpdateScript Download](http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx)